# Starting a form in C# console project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, console-application

My project is a console client. I start in the console and then display the form. I use the code below to display a blank form (I will add controls later) to the user. But the form is displayed, but it is stuck (not active). What should I do?

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting form");
Console_Client.Main mainform = new Main();
mainform.Show();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `ShowDialog()`.

The problem is that you're not running a message loop. There are two ways to start one. `ShowDialog()` has one integrated so that will work. The alternative is to use `Application.Run()`, either after the `Show()` call or with the form as a parameter.

1. `ShowDialog()`:

   ```
   mainform.ShowDialog();
   ```
2. `Application.Run()` without form:

   ```
   mainform.Show();
   Application.Run();
   ```
3. `Application.Run()` with the form:

   ```
   Application.Run(mainform);
   ```

All of these work.

Comment: ShowDialog() will work in some cases, but, without a real message pump, some functionality of forms will not behave the way you'd expect.  If the form is very simple, this is fine...

Comment: Using `ShowDialog()` works the same as when you would open a login form in the `Main` before the `Application.Run()`. Yes, for simple forms this works great.

Answer (score 5):

You need to start up a full application, just like a Windows Forms application normally does:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Starting form");
 Console_Client.Main mainform = new Main();

 // This will start the message loop, and show the mainform...
 Application.Run(mainform);

 // This won't occur until the form is closed, so is likely no longer required.
 // Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: using System.Windows.Forms;  is also needed

Comment: @vishnu: True, or it needs to be fully qualified.